# FFMPEG low bitrate at starting frames

Tags: ffmpeg

So I noticed that the first 1-4s of the videos that I'm converting start with a low bitrate and gradually increase untill its around the specified bitrate (`-crf 17 -minrate 2000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 2000k`).

```
...
frame= 37 fps= 0.0 q=24.0 size = 113kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate= 443.5kbits/s
frame= 66 fps= 64 q=30.0 size = 619kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate= 1581.6kbits/s
frame= 99 fps= 64 q=28.0 size = 1106kB time=00:00:04.52 bitrate= 2002.2kbits/s
frame= 131 fps= 63 q=23.0 size = 1599kB time=00:00:05.82 bitrate= 2247.8kbits/s
...
```

I already tried changing several settings like `-crf`, `-b:v`, `-minrate`, `-maxrate` and `-bufsize`. From my trial-and-error experience, the lower the `-crf` / higher `-b:v`, the faster it reaches an appropriate bitrate, but it still has this "lagg" in the beginning of the conversion.

Is it possible to immediately start with, for example 2000kbits/s, at the start of the conversion?

**EDIT**

Around the first 1-30s (roughly), the clips are more pixelated than the rest of the clip. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuIhb.png) image for a comparison (zoomed in on area of an 1080p clip). The rest of the clip doesn't have any visible loss like this (1850kbps encoded vs 2000kbps original), so I still assume it has something to do with the start of the encoding.

Comment: I wonder if the bitrate ramping up is just a result of the way ffmpeg is calculating it, perhaps averaging over the first 4 reports in your example.  Another thought is that maybe the first part of your clip has low information, like a mostly black title screen?

Comment: Well the clips don't have black title screens in particular, maybe a few frames, but not +/- 4 whole seconds / 100 frames. I think ffmpeg just needs some time "to warm up", but I don't know for sure.

Comment: It's showing the cumulative bitrate, not instantaneous.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - talking head video, white background, maybe a very quick fade-up at the start, but first 2-3 seconds show very pixellated. Anyone solve this?

Comment: I've seen this effect when reencoding Saving Private Ryan. The first 30 seconds are logos, followed by 30 seconds of static text on a black screen, and then 4 minutes of slow footage, and then the high action d-day landing scene. But my bitrates are 2-8kb/s for the first 12 seconds, 700kb/s for the next 3, then an even 2500kb/s until about 1:10 in.